# Is this an appropriate situation to use a poisson glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

I have some network data with a control and treatment group. Each group has a before and after network maps. I'd like to know if there are more independent components in the 'after' network maps for the treatment, compared to the 'before' network maps. The data looks like this (v small sample size):

```
       condition       num_components
1    before control              1
2    before control              1
3    before control              1
4    before control              1
5    before control              1
6     after control              1
7     after control              1
8     after control              5
9     after control              1
10    after control              3
11 before treatment              1
12 before treatment              1
13 before treatment              2
14 before treatment              1
15  after treatment              6
16  after treatment              2
17  after treatment              4
18  after treatment              9
```

Is it appropriate to use a poisson distributed GLM with the 'before' data as the reference group? If so, is there a way to check that these results are also different from the control?

Comment: Are the data paired at all?  do you know the number of components for the same sample, both before and after the treatment?  Or, are all the samples in your table independent?

Comment: The data aren't paired and I know the number of components for the same sample before and after the treatment (i.e. not independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to my comment is a bit confusing - if you know the number of components before and after, then it sounds like your data *is* paired.

Presumably, you could re-arrange your data so that each sample shows the number of components before and after.  You could then do a paired t-test, where your null hypothesis is that the difference between the number of components before and after is zero.  You *could* do this as a poisson glm, by including pair as a random effect - however, remember that your response is the *difference* between the numbers, not the counts themselves.  I'm assuming that it's possible for the number of components to go down as well as up?  I therefore imagine the response fits a normal distribution better than a poisson distribution, and a paired t-test would be fine.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, I thought you meant paired in the sense that the control and treatment are paired by something to make sure that they're similar groups. I think that poisson is probably a better fit as almost all of the 'before' data points are 1 and it would be impossible to have fewer than 1 component. I'll have a look at adding the ID as a random effect then! Thanks for your advice!